# While & Sentinel Values

Tags: python

I am learning Python and am trying to edit the code which has the following error:

> If you enter a negative number, it will be added to the total and count. Modify the code so that negative numbers give an error message instead (but don’t end the loop) Hint: elif is your friend.

```py
def checkout():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    moreItems = True
    while moreItems:
        price = float(input('Enter price of item (0 when done): '))
        if price != 0:
            count = count + 1
            total = total + price
            print('Subtotal: $', total)

        # This `elif` block is the code I edited
        elif price<0:
            print('Error')
            price= False

        else:
            moreItems = False
    average = total / count
    print('Total items:', count)
    print('Total $', total)
    print('Average price per item: $', average)

checkout()
```

How can I fix my code so it prints the "Error" message when a negative price is entered?

Comment: It will never be executed because of first if

Comment: Change first if statement  to this - `if price > 0:`  andy try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user submits a negative value to the `price` input, your code then runs `if price != 0:`.

To figure out what's going on more easily, I ran this code in the python shell:

```py
>>> total = 0
>>> count = 0
>>> moreItems = True

>>> price = float(input('Enter price of item (0 when done): '))
Enter price of item (0 when done): -5

>>> price != 0
True
```

What you probably want instead is:

```py
if price > 0:
    ...
elif price < 0:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Ah, it prevented the code from running, should have noticed that, thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line:

```
if price != 0:
```

to this one:

```
if price > 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

In `if else` or `if elif` statements, the code inside `else` or `elif` is only executed if the condition of `if` fails.

Ex:

```
if cond1:
    code1
elif cond2:
    code2
else:
    code3
```

if `cond1` is `true` then **only** `code1` will run. If not `cond2` will be checked, If True then **only** `code2` will tun, hence the word "else" (elif is the same as else if)

In you question:

> Modify the code so that negative numbers give an error message instead
> (but don’t end the loop) Hint: elif is your friend.

In your code, If price is negative then `price != 0` is True.
So because using elif, **only** this will run:

```
count = count + 1
total = total + price
print('Subtotal: $', total)
```

Code fix:

```
def checkout():
total = 0
count = 0
moreItems = True
while moreItems:
    price = float(input('Enter price of item (0 when done): '))
    **if price > 0:
        count = count + 1
        total = total + price
        print('Subtotal: $', total)
    elif price < 0:
        print('Error')
        price= False**
    else:
        moreItems = False
average = total / count
print('Total items:', count)
print('Total $', total)
print('Average price per item: $', average)

checkout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected..? I have only done a few minor changes.

```
def checkout():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    moreItems = True

    while moreItems:
        price = float(input('Enter price of item (0 when done): '))
        if price > 0:
            count += 1
            total += price
            print(f'Subtotal: $ {total}')
        elif price < 0:
            print('**Error**, Please enter a positive value')
        else:
            moreItems = False
    average = total / count
    print(f'Total items: {count}')
    print(f'Total $ {total}')
    print(f'Average price per item: $ {average}')

checkout()
```